# Dataclasses - Basic method chaining

Tags: python, python-dataclasses, python-class

I am trying to create a class, that has 2 methods:

- Query data (as a generator)
- Save as json

  ```
  @dataclass
  class Data_Query:
      hierarchic: str
      sku: bool
      pred_lenght: int

      def query(self, db):
         if (self.hierarchic == 'store' and self.sku == True):
             x = db.aggregate([{...}]);
             self.export_json(x) 

      def export_json(self, x, file):
          with open(f'/home/Documents/dataset/{file}', 'w') as fp:
              for i in x:
                  json.dump(i, fp)
                  fp.write('\n')
  ```

When I execute the query method, both methods are executed.

```
data = Data_Query('store', True, 56)
data.query(db)
```

What do I have to modify in order to call these methods separated ?

My expected output:

```
data.query(db).export_json('abc.json')
```

Comment: You had an error on identation. And query method was executed by query method `if (self.hierarchic == 'store' and self.sku == True):
        x = db.aggregate([{...}]);
        self.export_json(x) ` here

Comment: There's no apparent reason for `export_json` to be a method of `Data_Query` in the first place. All the data it needs is passed as two explicit arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling `export_json` directly from `query`, save the result in an instance attribute and return `self` to enable chaining. Then `export_json` looks for the saved query on the instance, rather than taking it as an argument.

```
@dataclass
class Data_Query:
    hierarchic: str
    sku: bool
    pred_lenght: int

    def query(self, db):
       if (self.hierarchic == 'store' and self.sku == True):
           self.x = db.aggregate([{...}]);
           # self.export_json(x) 
       return self

    def export_json(self, file):
        try:
            x = self.x
        except AttributeError:
            return
        
        with open(f'/home/Documents/dataset/{file}', 'w') as fp:
            for i in x:
                json.dump(i, fp)
                fp.write('\n')
        del self.x
```

Now you can write `data.query(db).export_json('abc.json')`, and the JSON file
will only be written if, in fact, a query takes place.

However, this isn't the greatest design. Nothing about `export_json` is specific to your class; it should be a regular function that takes a result and a file name
and that you call *after* you make a query, *if* the query returns any results. Something more like

```
@dataclass
class Data_Query:
    hierarchic: str
    sku: bool
    pred_lenght: int

    def query(self, db):
       if (self.hierarchic == 'store' and self.sku == True):
           return db.aggregate([{...}])

def export_json(self, x, file):
    with open(f'/home/Documents/dataset/{file}', 'w') as fp:
        for i in x:
            json.dump(i, fp)
            fp.write('\n')

result = data.query(db)
if result is not None:
    export_json(result, 'abc.json')
```

---

You *might* argue "Of course `export_json` is related to my class; it assumes that `x` is an iterable of objects, which is something defined by the `query` method." In that case, you might consider defining a `QueryResult` class, and make `export_json` a method of *that* class. Then `DataQuery.query` returns an instance of `QueryResult`, and chaining feels a little less arbitrary: you are exporting the *result*, not the *query*.

```
# By the way, I am assuming there is more to this class than a query
# method; otherwise, there should probably just be a regular function
# that takes the db, hierarchic, and sku as arguments.
@dataclass
class DataQuery:
    hierarchic: str
    sku: bool
    pred_length: int

    def query(self, db):
        result = None
        if self.hierarchic == 'store' and self.sku:
            result = db.aggregate(...)
        return QueryResult(result)


class QueryResult:
    def __init__(self, result):
        self.result = result

    def export_json(self, file):
        if self.result is None:
            return

        with open(f'/home/Documents/dataset/{file}', 'w') as fp:
           for i in x:
                json.dump(i, fp)
                fp.write('\n')


data.query(db).export_json('abc.json')
```

Comment: Thank you vert much @chepner, you really helped me. The last suggestion you proposed is exactly my case.